# Mobile Backend or Frontend integration with GetStream

Tags: getstream-io

From a Medium post in 2017, the recommendation from Stream is to use backend integration due to not placing the API secret into the frontend application. "our best practice is that your mobile application communicate with a fast backend API service hosted on your own systems, and that this backend application would communicate with Stream."

Now that stream supports user tokens, is doing backend integration still the recommended best practice for mobile applications?

Answer (score 0):

Backend integration is not necessary for the entire application, but for some operations, such as generating user JSON web tokens, a back-end is necessary. This is because exposing the secret client side exposes your API credentials.